# Copy data from one table to another without mapping all fields (Entity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework-6

Many similar questions but I cannot find a simple solution. I want to insert the result of below query to an archive table.

```
     var record = (from a in db.contacts
                      where a.id == 1
                      select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

If the table was just few columns it wouldn't be a problem to add it like that

```
    contacts_archive ca = new contacts_archive()
        {
            ca.id = record.id,
            ca.name = record.name,
            .....
        };

db.contacts_archive.Add(ca)
```

But what if my table has a hundred columns? Is there a better (quicker) way?

Answer (score 1):

If the property names match up exactly, you can use an auto mapper like AutoMapper or Mapster to do this for you.  Otherwise, you can use reflection and loop through the properties yourself if you don't wan to go through the trouble of adding a nuget package.

```
   contacts_archive ca = new contacts_archive();
   var archiveProps = ca.GetType().GetProperties();
   foreach (var prop in record.GetType().GetProperties()) {
      if (!archiveProps.Any(a => a.Name == prop.Name)) {
          continue;
      }
      prop.SetValue(ca, prop.GetValue(record));
   }
```

This assumes your names and property types match exactly, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ValueInjector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ValueInjecter/) or [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) to help you map similar fields from the source object to the destination object then just insert the generated destination object into the db. Here are some examples on how to use these nugets.
[ValueInector](http://sampathloku.blogspot.ug/2012/11/how-to-use-valueinjecter-with-aspnet.html) and [AutoMapper](https://cpratt.co/using-automapper-getting-started/)

Comment: Unless they changed it recently, I wouldn't use ValueInjector.  it is by far the slowest.